# How to use OAuth for the Google service

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, runtime-error, google-oauth

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application in VS2013 Ultimate Update 3

I am referring to the following resource for this question: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

1. I have navigated to the Google Developers Console.
2. I have created a new client ID with the correct Authorized JavaScript and correct Authorized redirect URI
3. I have entered in the client ID and client secret into the ConfigureAuth() public method in theStartup.Auth file

When clicking on the "Log in using your Google Account" button, I am getting the following error:

```
401. That’s an error.
Error: invalid_client
no application name
```

Can I please have some help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because you haven't inserted "PRODUCT NAME" in Consent Screen inside Google Developer Console.

So, log in into Google Developer Console and in [Consent Screen](https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~saak-webapi-test/apiui/consent), 
go to "APIs & auth" > "Consent screen" and enter a "PRODUCT NAME".

Note: Be sure that e-mail address is also provided.

Comment: I will be waiting for you to come back here and post when you have trouble with redirect urls and Owin Config :)

Comment: @user3210546 Well, it seems another problem. Ask a question providing more information and I'm sure someone will help you.